# awk + print lines from the first line until match word

Tags: linux, bash, awk, ksh

I want to print all lines from file until the match word
please advice how to do that with awk

for example

I want to print all lines until word PPP

remark the first line chuld be diff from AAA ( any word )

```
cat file.txt

AAA   ( the first line/word chuld be any word !!!!! )
BBB
JJJ
OOO
345
211
BBB
OOO
OOO
PPP
MMM
(((
&&&
```

so I need to get this

```
AAA
BBB
JJJ
OOO
345
211
BBB
OOO
OOO
PPP
```

other example  ( want to print until  KJGFGHJ )

```
 cat file.txt1

 HG
 KJGFGHJ
 KKKK
```

so I need to get

```
 HG
 KJGFGHJ
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk '1;/PPP/{exit}' file
AAA
BBB
JJJ
OOO
345
211
BBB
OOO
OOO
PPP
```

Comment: Same with above via `sed` : `sed '/PPP/q' infile`

Comment: @Costas: Yes, the OP want `awk`, so I don't give others tools.

Comment: The 1 at the beginning is like a full statement "// {print $0}" that is always matched. awk does not print without it.

Comment: @cidermole: Not exactly. `1` is like `{print $0}`. Also note that `//` is an empty pattern and the result is unspecified. It's work in `gawk`, `mawk`, Brian Kernighan own version but not in `nawk`, `oawk` from heirloom tools chest.

Comment: Thanks for the sed solution! I just want it done and I don't care about tool

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively use a range pattern matching the first line (NR equal to 1) until the first match of 'PPP' in a line

```
awk 'NR==1,/PPP/' file
```

if the line must exactly match 'PPP' only use

```
awk 'NR==1,/^PPP$/' file
```

If you would like to do the same for each file in the argument list, use the FNR variable which resets to 1 for the first line of each processed file

```
awk 'FNR==1,/PPP/' file1 file2 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

As OP said his first line or word of file can be contains any word(like `PPP` itself), so you need to check that and scape the first line from matching and avoid the `awk` to exit there.

Then you can try this:

#### Input file:

```
PPP # the first line/word chuld be any word !!!!! )
BBB
$$$
JJJ
OOO
PPP
345
PPP
%%%
```

#### Command:

```
awk '1;/PPP/{if (NR>1) exit}' file
```

#### Output:

```
PPP # the first line/word chuld be any word !!!!! )
BBB
$$$
JJJ
OOO
PPP
```